# Excel 365: Cannot paste values to visible cells only

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-excel-365

In Excel 365, I've selected visible cells only from a filtered selection. Cell count is 285, which is factual. I've tried copying and pasting from a different workbook a list which also counts 285 cells, but I'm getting the following warning:

```
You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size.
Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try 
pasting again.
```

Is there any workaround for this? Doesn't matter to me if it's an elaborate one, I can just try to write VBA to automate as much as possible for this procedure.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _"Cell count is 285.."_ are these the number of selected items... or the number of unfiltered items?

Comment: @p._phidot_ The former.

Answer (score 1):

The cell ranges are not the same. Some of the cells filtered out are still there, so Excel can't paste. Can you apply the formula to all the cells in the range, then hide the ones you don't want to see?

Comment: What formula do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

remove Filter.

Sort on the column on which you had filtered,

identify the rows that were "not" previously filtered out and delete them.

now you can paste the data from the other workbook below the data that is remaining after deletion.

This way, the filtered out will again become part of new combination of data.